# How to post list file from MVC to Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, post, asp.net-web-api, httppostedfilebase

In MVC , I use `HttpPostedFileBase` to get file from form (`multipart/form-data`) :

View :

```
<form role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="ProductCode"/>
    <input type="text" name="ProductCat"/>
    <input type="text" name="Price"/>
    <input type="text" name="file" multiple/>
</form>
```

Model :

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId{ set; get; }
    public string ProductCode { set; get; }
    public int ProductCat { set; get; }
    public decimal Price { set; get; }
} 
public class ProductData
{
    public Product pro { set; get; }
    public List<HttpPostedFileBase> file { set; get; } 
}
```

Action :

```
public ActionResult PostProduct(Product prop,List<HttpPostedFileBase> file)
{
    ProductData data = new ProductData();
    data.pro=prop;
    data.file=file;
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/99");    
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    HttpResponseMessage res = client.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/product/postproduct",data).Result;
    // in here , i get error :"error getting value from 'readtimeout' on 'system.web.httpinputstream'",and i cannot post data to web API
    if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return PartialView("_Success");
    }
    else
        return PartialView("_Error");
    }
```

In web API :

```
[Route("postproduct")]
[ResponseType(typeof(Product))]
public IHttpActionResult PostProduct(ProductData prod)
{
    ....
}
```

I don't know how to post data (model,file) from MVC to Web API?

Comment: Is this Web api endpoint part of the same website ? If yes, why you need to post it via Http ? You can keep the code inside the web api endpoint to a common class and call the method from your mvc action method ?

Comment: I know ,but i want to use Web APi for multi-platform. I want to save file to share for all platform using web API.

Answer (score 0):

It involves a bit of ceremony.

This article should take care of the basics of uploading a file with form parameters http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2.

For clarity, an example from the article:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostFormData()
{
    // Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
    }

    string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
    var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

    try
    {
        // Read the form data.
        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

        // This illustrates how to get the file names.
        foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName);
            Trace.WriteLine("Server file path: " + file.LocalFileName);
        }

        // Show all the key-value pairs.
        foreach (var key in provider.FormData.AllKeys)
        {
            foreach (var val in provider.FormData.GetValues(key))
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", key, val));
            }
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
    }
}
```